# What is this type of PowerShell array using @"..."@?

Tags: powershell

Recently, I saw a PowerShell array written like this:

```
$qCommand = @"
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
<Query>
    <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>
</Query>
<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">5000</RowLimit>
</View>
"@
```

I've not encountered this kind of syntax yet with PowerShell arrays, only the standard `@()`.

What's `@"..."@` for?

Comment: Run the command `help about_Quoting_Rules` and read on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an array but rather a [Here-String](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx).

> The Here-String construction provides an easy way for handling text, it's specialty is dealing with speech marks and other delimiters without the need for inserting escape characters.

Quoted from: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_here_string.htm